# Boiling/washing used guitar/bass strings - is it worthwhile?

Tags: guitar, strings, bass-guitar

I've read that some people boil their strings from time to time to make them sound again like they were new (and save some money).

Is this really worthwhile, or are there any disadvantages to this?

Comment: Note that it's very hard to get a string back on if you cut off the excess string after mounting it. Which means you have to play the bass guitar with unsightly strings sticking out of the guitar head, and potentially hitting things and people, which is why I never did this.

Comment: I have a Steinberger style bass with double ball ends and I have boiled the strings, of course, there is not a problem with putting the strings back on this type of bass. The D'Addario ESXL160 strings that I use on it last a long time, when I was gigging 3 times a week, about a year, then I would boil them and go another 6 mos. Today, however, being strictly a studio dog and a multi instrumentalist, I just change them out when they go dead, so this current set has been on about 3 years and still sound good. Timothy
[timothybussmusic.com](http://timothybussmusic.com)

Comment: @LennartRegebro Just cut the string a few inches past the tuner *before* putting it on for the first time, then start putting the string on by winding it round the tuner. No sticking out wire, and you can swap strings as many times as you want.

Comment: I honestly don't know what you mean. Either the string is too long, and hence sticks out, or it doesn't.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a trick that's been around for ages, with many variations - I've even heard that the use of certain bodily fluids gives good results, but it isn't something I'm about to try.

The main reason to do this is to save money, but you should ask yourself whether the savings are worth it. It's generally a better idea to keep your strings in good shape - wiping them clean of grime and sweat after playing and giving them a rubdown with string-cleaner every now and again. Boiling is a short-term remedy and if you've been taking care of your strings on a regular basis, by the time it becomes an option, you really should think about changing them.

The key drawback of boiling is that you must take the strings off and put them on again - which, unfortunately, exposes them to certain risks. For a start, once they've been wound onto the tuning pegs, the wire is permanently disfigured. This isn't a problem as long as they remain wound on, but removing them and putting them back on may make it a factor in tuning, consistent string vibration and overall strength - bend and straighten a wire too many times and it breaks. You can take care in putting the strings back on again in order to achieve an near-identical string position as originally, however, it's likely that you will end up with some inconsistency. String tension will take care of it to an extent, but the string won't perform as well as when it was originally put on. With wound strings, an additional problem might be distortion of the windings for the exact same reason.

My suggestion would be to resort to boiling only when left with no other option. It really shouldn't be seen as a standard method of extending string life.

Comment: Great answer. The only thing I would add is that unless you are playing a fretless bass, by the time the strings might need boiling, they will have worn spots under each fret that boiling will not take away.  This too will affect the tone.

Answer (score 9):

I used to do this with bass strings, and it does make a difference.  They'll brighten up and sound like new, but not for as long as they did right out of the package.  It's a bit of a pain, though, because of course to remove the strings, you have to fully unwind them rather than simply cut them, so it takes longer.

I wouldn't try this with guitar strings, mostly because the marginal cost savings doesn't seem worth it.  Also, I'm not sure if it would make much difference with plain strings---the idea behind boiling is that it clears out dead skin stuck between the windings, which of course plain strings don't have.

Comment: Metal polish is also pretty good for bringing plain string back from the brink (and wound).  Draws a lot of the tarnish out, though its only worth doing in an emergency IMO

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about boiling, etc unless absolutely necessary due to very limited finances.  Because out of all honesty, nothing sounds like a new fresh set of strings!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, when I put a new set of guitar or bass strings (roundwound) on, I only get about **2 sets worth** (1.5 hours) of playing and they are dead! I tried all brands and none lasted any longer than the D"Adarrio's. I definately have a body chemical issue! I played Bass in a hard rock band for 20 years, and I did boil each set of strings **between each gig** and it did work. Ocassinally, they would last longer after boiling and then rubbing alcohol wiping then when new? Nobody ever let me touch their bass because they knew what I would do to their strings....

Answer (score 1):

Don't boil old strings; once they're gone they're gone.  I boil my new set right out of the package, it makes them softer and more pliable.  That's an old John Entwisle trick, it works.